# Importar uma biblioteca js no Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Estou com dificuldades em importar as bibliotecas js no vuejs estou sempre a receber o seguinte erro na consola.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou a fazer o load das mesmas no ficheiro index.html da pasta public

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
  <script src="/src/js/detect_mobile.js"></script>
  <script src="/src/js/anime.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/src/js/animationjs.js"></script>
  <script src="/src/js/main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

"Para importar arquivos .js em um arquivo .vue, eu costumo utilizar o import (import syntax), segue abaixo:

```
import forms from './assets/js/pages/forms'; // verifique se o diretório está correto
```

Se o js possuir um export, como por exemplo um export function, pode ser importado uma função desta forma:

```
import { nomeDaFuncao } from 'nome-do-arquivo';
```

E no arquivo nome-do-arquivo.js seria assim:

```
export function nomeDaFuncao () 
{
 // código
}
```

Ou seja, na minha experiência usualmente o arquivo .js exporta algo que posteriormente em um componente .vue poderá importar em sua tag . Note que não precisa ser necessariamente uma função para ser exportada, pode se utilizar export default ou module.exports para objetos.

Observação: Usualmente possuo duas "aplicações" separadas, o front-end em Vuejs e o back-end em Laravel, diferente do seu exemplo que no caso pelo que entendi está tudo no mesmo local. Não tive tempo de testar, mas pelo que entendo e pesquisei creio que funcionará. Podem editar/corrigir caso eu esteja errado, estou tentando ajudar com o que sei."

**Coloquei entre aspas porque obtive a resposta de uma pergunta similar**

Fonte:[Importar js file em template vuejs e laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/268642/importar-js-file-em-template-vuejs-e-laravel#268647)